# How to create two dimensional array of Observable<String>?

Tags: java, rx-java

As for now in my model I have two dimensional array of strings.

```
private final String[][] table;
```

I want to use Observable to merge/combine/filter etc. data in this table. Something like this:

```
Observable
   .combineLatest(
       table.getCell(1,1),
       table.getCell(1,2),
       (valueA, valueB) -> valueA + valueB )
   .subscribe( result -> System.out.println( result ));
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use a `List<List<Observable<String>>>`? Arrays should be avoided in general.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: `table[1][1]` ??